Github repos: Inconsistency in 2 ways of download repos zip file: 1) Click and download, 2) Use the link and wget it
I was trying to programmatically install an private repo. I could not git clone it because of the firewall (maybe something else). However I could manually download the zip file so I want to programmatically download the zip file, unzip it, cd into it  and use "pip install -e ." to install it.
First of all, it works if I do it manually. the downloaded file is called "MaxRepo-master.zip", I can unzip it, cd into the project and install using "pip install -e ".
When I tried to use the link (click and copy link address), the link looks like this:
https://github.com/MaxAccount/maxRepos/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
The zip file is "master.zip", not the "MaxRepo-master.zip". The later is what I would get if I just click and download.  So this is the first weird thing I observe.
The second thing is: I could not unzip the file. It ends up ith this kind of error message:
-------------  error message:
$ unzip master.zip
Archive:  master.zip
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of master.zip or
master.zip.zip, and cannot find master.zip.ZIP, period.
What I desire is to download the file with the name: "MaxRepo-master.zip". And after upzipping, I would get the folder like: MaxRepo-master. And then I can install it.
Thanks in advance for anybody who could help or give me some hints.
